# Azure VM creation failed using downloaded template (The entity name 'vmImageName' is invalid according to its validation rule)

Tags: azure

I want to create a vm on azure using az cli.
So I created interactively a VM and downloaded the template and its parameters.
I added some missing parameters, the final script is

`az deployment group create --resource-group my-rg --template-file ./azure-32Go.template.json --parameters @./azure-32Go.template.parameters --parameters publicIpAddressName=my-ip  networkInterfaceName=my-nic adminPublicKey="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" imageName=MsOps-Demo1-image-20210212-175858 --debug`

I get an error

```
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: DeploymentFailed
Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
Exception Details:
    Error Code: BadRequest
    Message: {'error': {'code': 'InvalidParameter', 'message': "The entity name 'vmImageName' is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\\W][\\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$.", 'target': 'vmImageName'}}
```

Googling did not point me to someone to get the same issue.
I looked in azur portal Resource Group / Activity log to look at more information, but I only see the same above issue with no more information

How can I fix my code ?

Comment: `imageName="MsOps-Demo1-image-20210212-175858"` ?

Comment: Could you please share content of the files azure-32Go.template.json and azure-32Go.template.parameters?

Comment: Please also check that - Image name starts with alphanumeric. End with alphanumeric or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I auto answer this question.

I have redone the whole process, and starting the vm with the template works fine.

As I wanted to set a specific image name. I added a parameter *imageName*

Now I updated the template.json by adding a parameter

```
"parameters": {
           "location": {
               "type": "string"
           },
           "imageName": {
               "type": "string"
           },
           "networkInterfaceName": {
```

Updated where it is used

```
 "storageProfile": {
       "osDisk": {
           "createOption": "fromImage",
           "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
              }
           },
       "imageReference": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/14b6e880-753e-4a5f-8618-c0786702aa1c/resourceGroups/MsOps-Horizon-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/[parameters('imageName')]"
       }
 },
```

But when doing the creation process fails with the same reason

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 39b18e50-ff0d-4ecd-a3e8-e40b988a341b. {
   "error": {
     "code": "InvalidParameter",
     "message": "The entity name 'vmImageName' is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\\W][\\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$.",
     "target": "vmImageName"
   }
 }
 Creation of vm failed
```

My workaround is therefore to do a *sed* in the template.json to insert the image name I want :(

My guess is that the *[parameter('imageName')]* is not expanded early enough which makes the process fails as the name does not match the matching rule